# Get variables set in build.gradle in Jenkins pipeline build

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I have a Jenkins pipeline job that builds my project using gradle. As part of the build i would like to use a global variable I have set in the `build.gradle` file

```
project.ext.set("MyVar", "My Value")
```

How can i access this variable in the pipeline build, so

```
myVar = varSetInGradleBuild
```

Hope that makes sense

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually dependency is reverse, Jenkins sets variables for build to control behavior with `-P` key.

For your use case you can define variables in `gradle.properties` file and read it in Jenkins pipeline.